# Как правильно организовать страницу с формой?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Первоначально при загрузке страницы отображается только один блок с двумя радиокнопками. При выборе  радиокнопки необходимо, чтобы подгрузились несколько блоков с НЕ одинаковыми **label** и **input**. В зависимости от выбранной кнопки, это должны быть разные блоки (при нажатии радиокнопки, например, *авто*, будут **label'ы** и **input'ы** с вводом данных о авто и при нажатии *мотоциклы* - о мотоциклах). Блок с радиокнопками остается выше динамически подгруженных блоков с **label** и **input**.
Опыта с написанием html и jQuery очень мало.
Вопрос такой. Как обычно организовывают такую динамическую подгрузку разных форм? Есть необходимость в разметке html или же достаточно использовать только JS/jQuery?

Примитивная модель:

```html
<div id="content">
  <form method="post" action="/">
    <h2>Светофор</h2>
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="light" value="red" />
    <label for="red">Красный</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="green" name="light" value="green" />
    <label for="green">Зеленый</label><br />
    <div>Что вы будете делать, когда горит красный сигнал светофора:</div>
    <input class="input" id="red_answer" type="text" />
    <div>Что вы будете делать, когда горит зеленый сигнал светофора:</div>
    <input class="input" id="green_answer" type="text" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Изначально есть это:

```html
<div id="content">
  <form method="post" action="/">
    <h2>Светофор</h2>
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="light" value="red" />
    <label for="red">Красный</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="green" name="light" value="green" />
    <label for="green">Зеленый</label><br />
  </form>
</div>
```

При нажатии кнопки **Красный**, станет так:

```html
<div id="content">
  <form method="post" action="/">
    <h2>Светофор</h2>
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="light" value="red" />
    <label for="red">Красный</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="green" name="light" value="green" />
    <label for="green">Зеленый</label><br />
    <div>Что вы будете делать, когда горит красный сигнал светофора:</div>
    <input class="input" id="red_answer" type="text" />
  </form>
</div>
```

При нажатии **Зеленый** - соответствующий зеленый *блок*.

Comment: Судя по тому что я представил себе - это вообще можно сделать без JS. Покажите пожалуйста все основные этапы вашей логики картинками

Comment: Поправил свой пост - как смог. Идея примерно такая. Но только при выборе соответствующих радиокнопок, там будет не один блок, а несколько.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выбрать другие селекторы, чтобы упростить CSS (например вместо `for` аттрибута в `div`-е использовать класс), но в целом логика не изменится. Про тильду в селекторе можно прочитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

```css
[for="red"]:not(label),
[for="green"]:not(label) {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"][id="red"]:checked ~ [for="red"]:not(label) {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="radio"][id="green"]:checked ~ [for="green"]:not(label) {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form method="post" action="/">
    <h2>Светофор</h2>
    <input type="radio" id="red" name="light" value="red" />
    <label for="red">Красный</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="green" name="light" value="green" />
    <label for="green">Зеленый</label><br />
    <div for="red">
      <div>Что вы будете делать, когда горит красный сигнал светофора:</div>
      <input class="input" id="red_answer" type="text" />
    </div>
    
    <div for="green">
      <div>Что вы будете делать, когда горит зеленый сигнал светофора:</div>
      <input class="input" id="green_answer" type="text" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```